# DemoActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-gradle-plugin, lint

i get the following error in my gradle console. Tried looking for the deprecated API but couldn't find it. Thanks in advance!!!

Error: 
DemoActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with 
-Xlint:deprecation for details.

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String TAG = "DemoActivity";
DrawerLayout mDrawerlDrawerLayout;
FrameLayout actContent;
private LinearLayout linear;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarToggle;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ImageView mImageView;
private int height;
private SlidingUpPanelLayout mSlidingUpPanelLayout;
private ListView drawerListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> navigationDrawerAdapter;
private String[] drawerItem = {"Email", "Wink", "Favourite", "Match me", "About"};

    @Override
    public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    linear = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.base_activity, null);
    actContent = (FrameLayout) linear.findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
    mDrawerlDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) linear.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    // set the drawer layout as base_activity content view of Activity.


    toolbar = (Toolbar) linear.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) linear.findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar));
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.demo);
    //toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    setContentView(linear);
    // add layout of BaseActivities inside framelayout.i.e. frame_container
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, actContent, true);

    initDrawerView();
    initDrawer();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.demo, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.e("Drawer", "clicked");
    if (actionBarToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        Log.e("Drawer item clicked", "clicked");
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        Log.e("Drawer item clicked item id", "clicked");
        try {
            if (mDrawerlDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerListView)) {
                mDrawerlDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListView);
            } else {
                mDrawerlDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerListView);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search: {
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.action_settings: {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void initDrawerView() {
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    mDrawerlDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationDrawerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BaseActivity.this,   
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, drawerItem);
    drawerListView.setAdapter(navigationDrawerAdapter);
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

private void initDrawer() {
    actionBarToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(BaseActivity.this, mDrawerlDrawerLayout, toolbar, 
R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
    mDrawerlDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            Log.e("Drawer item click", "click");
            mDrawerlDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion: compile with -Xlint, if so what is the output?

Comment: I did and got the solution...I was using wrong import statement..Thanks for help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of the appcompat library.  Can you show the import statements that this class uses?

Based on the newer version of appcompat, use

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

instead of

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Also, reference the new version of appcompat in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

More on the deprecated class at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html

Comment: The link you provided is...deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the project. If still that doesn't work try link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html. This issue is caused basically due to the older version of appcompact library.

Comment: How does your link help figure out what libraries have been deprecated?