# My App cannot build because of the following logcat error which i do not even understand

Tags: android, android-studio

here is the logcat. i need clarification on this error, please community

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: `com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: me`thod ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

i did the changes but again  i get this error??

```
11-28 13:36:28.308 19872-19872/com.example.moses.nganya E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.moses.nganya, PID: 19872
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.moses.nganya/com.example.moses.nganya.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
```

Comment: You might exceeded the methods limit,  you can try multidex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714651/android-studio-dexindexoverflowexception-method-id-not-in

Answer (score 0):

please refer [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).The reason is you have exceeded the method limit.This is mainly due to usage of google-play-services or any other large libraries.Try to use only required components if using google-play-services.List of individual libraries can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup?utm_campaign=dex-1214&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)