# Error when running project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Please see the image above.

How can I resolve this error?

My Windows PC has 4 GB RAM and only 6GB of available space in my C Drive.

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to enable multiDex support, take a look at my answer here: 
[Android Studio DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714651/android-studio-dexindexoverflowexception-method-id-not-in/38715060#38715060)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set max heap size >= your pc ram. Decrease it.
Open `build.gradle`

Find

```
dexOptions { incremental true javaMaxHeapSize "4g" }
```

change `4g` to `1g` or `2g`