# Getting error when trying to generate signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am trying to generate a signed APK for my app, however, i am getting two of the below error messages. Please see my Android Manifesto file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.elderlywatch.elderlywatch">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:name=".FallDetectorSettings.SettingValues"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:taskAffinity="">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HRDetailsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".FallDetectHomeActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactDetailsActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FallDetectSettingActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MonitoringFallActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SMSSendActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service android:name=".FallDetectorAccelerometer.DetectingFalls" >
        </service>
        <activity
            android:name=".SMSDetailsActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am getting the below two error messages and please can someone help me as I am struggling to generate a singed APK. I am able to build my app, however, when trying to create a API I always get the two error messages indicated below.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
> >     0xffff]: 65536

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
  <application
            android:name=".ApplicationState"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

and add this

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        **android:name=".ApplicationState"**
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:name=".FallDetectorSettings.SettingValues"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in your gradle (app) inside android{} place this

```
   lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

for dex error follow the solution given by android in the below link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: can you update you above manifest again according to new one?

Comment: i do have updated my answer. What is that error message.

Comment: ok for dex error https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html  follow this link instruction

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> \AndroidManifest.xml **Error:(48)** Error: The element must be a direct
>   child of the root element [WrongManifestParent] Error:Execution failed
>   for task ':mobile:lintVitalRelease'.

This indicates that you need to look at line 48 of your manifest.xml

That line looks like:

```
<application
            android:name=".ApplicationState"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

That's a second xml <application> tag.
It tells you that tag must be a direct child of the root.

Probably just remove it and it will work.

Comment: If I remove it will it not affect my app from crashing?

Comment: It should not.  save it off to make sure you can get back to it. But there should only be one application tag that is a direct child of the manifest tag.

Comment: I am now getting this error message. Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Comment: Well, it's a different problem now.  Look at this for that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714651/android-studio-dexindexoverflowexception-method-id-not-in